# What could cause the power-on hours of a disk to reset?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, hard-drive-failure

I have three hard disks in my laptop, bought about 4½ years ago (March 2013). One 500 GB disk is from an older laptop (so 5+ years old), one 500 GB came with the laptop, and I added a 1 TB disk two years ago (October 2015). I wanted to see how my disks were doing, and to check which disk was the oldest.

Looking at the SMART info (via the GNOME Disks app and `smartctl` commands), I get powered-on-since times of:

- 3 years, 5 months and 11 days for one 500 GB disk (model: ST9500423AS (0001SDM5))
- 2 years, 11 months and 1 day for the second (model: WDC WD5000LPVT-75G33T0 (01.01A01)),
- 11 months and 11 days for the 1 TB disk (model: HGST HTS721010A9E630 (JB0OA3J0))

Now that doesn't look right. What could have caused the power-on times to be so different from actual values?

I have fiddled around with the laptop's internals a few times, possibly swapping disks (I'm not sure). Could that be it?

---

I know I could get the actual ages using serial numbers and vendor sites, but that's not what I am after here. I already identified the disks by looking at my order histories:

- the Western Digital one was bought in September 2012
- making the Seagate disk the one that came with the laptop.

Comment: For a start it's power-on hours as such it should only be the time you actually had your system running. In addition, just my guess, head parking etc. might influence this further.

Comment: @Seth in that case, two of those values should be the same (I added the older 500 GB disk soon after I got the laptop, so it should at least be as old as the other). And the third should be waay less than half of 2 years (I run my laptop about 4-5 hours a day).